# Prevent sitecore from creating the the sitename#lang cookie

Tags: cookies

Is there a way to block sitecore from creating the {website}#lang cookie?

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/cookies-used-by-sitecore.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the same processor but you might try the follow which removes the site cookie.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <httpRequestProcessed>
        <processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.HttpRequest.StoreSiteNameInCookie, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite">
          <patch:delete />
        </processor>
      </httpRequestProcessed>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried what was suggested by both Michael and Marek. Looks like it better not to attempt this. Thank you!

Comment: Adding my custom processor in the `httpRequestProcessed` pipeline has worked a treat to remove the `[website]#lang` cookies, much better than the `httpRequestEnd` pipeline I initially tried.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `{sitename}#lang` cookie is set by the `LanguageResolver` processor.

There is a code

```
args.SitecoreContext.Language = lang;
```

And in the background, setter of the `Language` property of the context calls

```
  string cookieKey = site.GetCookieKey("lang");
  WebUtil.SetCookieValue(cookieKey, language.Name, expiryDate ?? DateTime.MinValue);
```

I haven't found any option to stop Sitecore from creating that cookie.

The only option would be to add a custom processor to `httpRequestBegin` processor after `Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver` processor and in that processor remove the cookie from the response.